# What's the quickest way to remove all items in a WinJS ListView?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

I want to remove all items in a WinJS ListView.  What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to set the itemDataSource property to null.

```
listview.winControl.itemDataSource = null;
```

When you need to start adding new items back in, just create a new Binding.List and populate it.  You could also create a new empty Binding List and assign that...

```
var newList = new WinJS.Binding.List([]);
listview.winControl.itemDataSource = newList;
```

Comment: You can also ask your existing data source to raise a reset event - WinJS.Binding.List has a clear function iirc

Comment: @Dominic - Strangely enough, it does not have a `clear` method. But you can roll your own with something like `WinJS.Binding.List.prototype.clear = function() { while(this.length > 0) this.pop(); };`

Comment: If i have a 'class' module with a WinJS.Binding.List as a member prop, which is then bound to a ListView, can I still simply replace the member prop object with a new list? Would it blow up due to the notification subscriptions the ListView still holds to the old list reference? It seems @shovavnik's suggestion is the safest route in that case, but thought I'd ask

Comment: also, if I follow the `pop` route (heh...), do I need to call `list.dataSource.beginEdits()` before the `while` along with `endEdits()` afterwards? The documentation is a bit vague on how these methods should be used.

Comment: the problem with that mechanism is if you have any binding set to the list they will be removed.  Using splice(0,list.lenght) retains any bindings.

Answer (score 8):

I prefer this way:

```
list.splice(0, list.length);
```

The third parameter is optional...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700810.aspx

Comment: It would be quicker to bind a new, empty list to the variable, unless some other state about the list needs to be retained.

Comment: I think it depends on the size of the list. For small lists, the splice() function works fine...

Comment: So this works OK if you assume that it'll never be passed much data or used very often (many repetitions of unnecessary work add up, whether in parallel or serial).  These are reasons why I would avoid this solution unless I knew I had to preserve some state other than the list contents.

Comment: This mechanism retains bindings that you might have added (such as to the "length" property)

Comment: Keeping bindings intact is a huge reason to use this method.